# How to connect 3 slave devices to one master if there are only 2 chip select pins

Tags: microcontroller, adc, spi

I need help figuring out how to interface the microcontroller Teensy 4.0 to three ADCs via SPI. The microcontroller only has 2 chip select pins according to its spec sheet. How can I connect to three slave devices with only 2 chip select pins? I know we can daisy chain them, but I prefer not to do that.

Link to Microcontroller: https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensy40.html
Link to ADC data sheet:https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7606B.pdf

Comment: why do you prefer not to use a simple solution to your problem?

Comment: Most systems allow the use of any CS/SS pin... Since it is not really a high speed system.

Comment: Are you sure those CS pins are for master mode? Isn't it just for case when your microcontroller acts as a slave?

Answer (score 1):

Two bits is enough to encode the 4 states you need (each of 3 slave chips selected, and none selected). You can use a 2:4 decoder with active-low outputs such as the [SN74LVC1G139](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G139). You may need to modify the software SPI driver to use an encoded CS output instead of the standard "one hot" style.

Answer (score 0):

If the micro-controller does not allow random CS/SS pins, consider running it through a 1:2 mux, and just set the correct chip using software before starting an SPI read/write. There are a lot of assumptions like hardware buffers etc. that the read/write will be done before you change the pin again...

Only use this method for occasional reads? Or with through testing...